# Iterate through a list of list in the form of a matrix but avoid a set of columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy, matrix

So I have a list of list :-

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,7]]
```

I want to iterate through the contents and avoid a certain column. So my general for loop structure is as follows:

```
for i in range (0,len(a[0])):
```

Now as far as I know I need one more condition to avoid a certain column. How do I do that?

Another way this could be done is to delete the whole column and append it right to the end.

So after deleting the column:

```
a = [[1,2,4],[5,6,8],[4,5,7]]
```

After appending:

```
a = [[1,2,4,3],[5,6,8,7],[4,5,7,6]]
```

I could use numpy to do this. So I am deleting the desired column from numpy.
Here's a working code:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,7]]
a_np= np.array(a)
a_col_data = a_np[:,2]
a1 = np.delete(a_np, 2 , axis = 1)
```

Now my a_col_data is `[3 7 6]`

I cannot append in this format. I need it in this format `[[3],[7],[6]]`
Then I could use the following code to append it as a last column in a:

```
np.append(a_np, a_col_data, axis=1)
```

Now issues with this approach, that I am facing:
How to convert a list `[3 7 6]` into `[[3],[7],[6]]`?
Considering I have a list of 150 columns and 3000 rows I can't do it manually.

Another issue is np.array converts the list into a pure matrix like structure removing the "," between elements. I want to get the list structure back.
For example:

```
a = [[1,2,4],[5,6,8],[4,5,7]]
a_np = [[1 2 4][5 6 8][4 5 7]]
```

How do I convert a_np to a again?

EDIT:

Ok I was just browsing stackoverflow and I got a solution. I could simply do the following to convert it back:

```
a_np.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

You could add an extra axis to `a_col_data`:

```
>>> a_np2 = np.append(a1, a_col_data[:, np.newaxis], axis=1)
>>> a_np2
array([[1, 2, 4, 3],
       [5, 6, 8, 7],
       [4, 5, 7, 6]])
>>> a_np2.tolist()
[[1, 2, 4, 3], [5, 6, 8, 7], [4, 5, 7, 6]]
```

Or you could avoid going the numpy route by using `enumerate`:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,7]]
for i in a:
    for j, x in enumerate(i):
        if j == 2:
            continue
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. One quick query :- If my list is a = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0] .....]. How do I remove the decimal and make it a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6] .....]

Comment: @Skyfail **Lazy answer**: `np.array(a).astype(int).tolist()`. **Better answer**: use a nested list comprehension and cast each float to integer. You may also accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks again. But why is a nested list comprehension method better than the lazy answer you provided ?

Comment: The overhead of converting to `np.array` is something to consider with the first method

Answer (score 0):

So you have a list of lists and want a list of lists in return, each missing one entry in the list?  Assuming you want to remove the item at index 2 of each sublist:

```
a = [[x for i, x in enumerate(sublist) is i != 2] for sublist in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns 0, 1 and 2 from you array you could do e.g.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[4,5,6,7]])
for col in a[:,[0,1,2]].T:
    print col
```